# Add link in markdown toggle switch in GitHub

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I wanna try to add a link in the toggle switch but seems the link doesn't work.
[image]

Markdown

```
<details>
  <summary>Link Test</summary>
  [Quick FInd](https://github.com/x/y/edit/main/DS-AL.md)
</details>
```

Is it possible to add a link in the toggle switch for the GitHub markdown?

Comment: Can you try `<a href="https://github.com/x/y/edit/main/DS-AL.md">Quick FInd</a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add some whitespace:

```markdown
<details>
  <summary>Link Test</summary>

  [Quick FInd](https://github.com/x/y/edit/main/DS-AL.md)

</details>
```

[GFM processes Markdown inside block-level HTML tags when separated by blank lines](https://github.github.com/gfm/#example-157).